# Approximating the cumulative space in subdirectories

Tags: bash

When I want to estimate the space required for all files in some tree, I can reach for `du`, and get an estimate of the total usage, and also an estimate of the space used within each subdirectory.

How do I produce that same set of estimates by subdirectories, when I want to filter the files that are included in the estimmate?

Alternative spelling of this same question: I have a long list of matching files from `find`, and I want to estimate the space used by each of the subdirectories that include those files.

*Clarification*: I'm not looking for size of all files in subdirectory that contains a match, but the aggregated size of the *matches* in that subdirectory.

```
A
+—— B
   +—— C
   |  +— x.txt
   |  +- y.jpg
   |  +- W.ignored
   |
   +—— D
      +- z.doc
      +- V.conf
```

With the layout above, and a match/list of files that includes x.txt, y.jpg, and z.doc

```
estimate(C) === estimate (x.txt, y.jpg)
estimate(D) === estimate (z.doc)
estimate(B) === estimate (C) + estimate (D)
estimate(A) === estimate (B)
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: There is no direct way to do this, with `find` and a bit of string manipulation, `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'x="{}"; y="${x%/*}"; du -sh "$y" ;' \;` Can you let me know if it works for huge directories, could not confirm on my minimal folders.

Comment: Depends on how your subdirectory tree looks like. Do you want the immediate directory above the files summed up, or the first level directory? (In both cases you can get quite 'legible' solution by `find | stat  | cut | awk`, or just uniq the directories and pipe them to `xargs du`